# SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I have a problem regarding in joining two tables with a WHERE clause on it which involves monthname(date)='$month'..

```
**tbl_dv**
dv_id, number, net, respo, date_added 

**tbl_payroll**
pr_id, dv_id, number, pr_date, roll1, roll2, roll3, roll4, roll5, roll6 date_added.
```

I want to add up the column ROLLS and view it on the view.php. Like: $total=(roll1 + roll2 + roll3 + roll4 + roll5 + roll6); How can do it and insert it in unique way.

```
$viewrecord = "SELECT * FROM tbl_dv WHERE respo='".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."' && year(date_added)='$year' && month(date_added)='$month'";
```

Comment: By looking at the columns roll1 ... roll6, it seems to me that you did not [normalize db design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @Krister Andersson Sorry for it. I was rushing things up. While this system was running already. But I have given time i'll patch up things and normalize this db design. For now I was looking assistance.. Thank you very much for your comments. If you want ill send you the design dummy system so that you can work it hand on hand..

Comment: It would be more efficient to reverse your logic. Also, anytime I see columns named x1, x2, etc. alarm bells start ringing vis–à–vis normalization (or lack thereof)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a -

```
$viewrecord = "SELECT *, (roll1 + roll2 + roll3 + roll4 + roll5 + roll6) as total FROM tbl_dv join tbl_payroll on tbl_dv.dv_id = tbl_payroll.dv_id WHERE respo='".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."' && year(date_added)='$year' && month(date_added)='$month'";
```

Comment: I have tried this code but i have this error Column 'respo' in where clause is ambiguous.

Comment: change it to tbl_dv.respo

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php require_once('../includes/connection.php');?>
<?php require_once('../includes/header.php');?>

<?php
$color="1";
$respo = $_GET['respo'];
$data = explode("+", $respo);
$month = date("m", strtotime($data[1])) . "<br />";
$year = date("Y", strtotime($data[1])) . "<br />";

**$viewrecord = "SELECT *, (pr.roll1 + pr.roll2 + pr.roll3 + pr.roll4 + pr.roll5 + pr.roll6) AS rolls FROM tbl_payroll dv join tbl_payroll pr on pr.dv_id = dv.dv_id WHERE dv.respo='".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."' && year(dv.date_added)='$year' && month(dv.date_added)='$month'";**
$run_viewrecord = mysql_query($viewrecord) or die(mysql_error());

{
echo "<table border='1' width='100%' style='border:1px solid silver' cellpadding='5px' cellspacing='0px'>
<tr bgcolor='#666666' style='color:#FFFFFF'>
<th>Date Encoded</th>
------------HEADER--------- etc....

-------THERE SHOULD BE A IF STATEMATE HERE-----------------
(where if no records match "dv.dv_id=pr.pr.dv_id". It would still display records from tbl_dv..)

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($run_viewrecord)) {

if($color==1){
echo "<tr bgcolor='#ffffff'>";
echo "<td align='center'>" .date_format(date_create($row[17]), "m/d/y")."</td>
**--------- I WANT TO DISPLAY THE ROLLS HERE --------------------**
echo "</td></tr>";

$color="2";
}   else {
echo "<tr bgcolor='#ebeaea'>";
echo "<td align='center'>" .date_format(date_create($row[17]), "m/d/y")."</td>
**--------- I WANT TO DISPLAY THE ROLLS HERE --------------------**
echo "</td></tr>";

$color="1";
}
}
echo '</table>';
echo '<td><tr><table><br /><br />';
}
?>
```

I was hoping to add an IF statement before WHILE. Which will still display records even there is no match dv_id on both table2. It should still display records.. The COLUMN ROLLS IF No match it will display a 0.00 value. LINK>> http://i599.photobucket.com/albums/tt79/emcevo/viewphpdisplay_zpsfc6a8174.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You could do this programatically by adding up the returned values for each record row in PHP.

You could also do something like

```
 $viewrecord = "SELECT *, (pr.roll1 + pr.roll2 + 
                pr.roll3 + pr.roll4 + pr.roll5 + pr.roll6) as rolls 
 FROM tbl_dv dv LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_payroll pr on dv.dv_id = pr.dv_id 
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_payroll pr on dv.dv_id = pr.dv_id 
 WHERE dv.respo='".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."' 
 && year(dv.date_added)='$year' && month(dv.date_added)='$month'";
```

Comment: The rolls are from the different table. Which I tried this one.. I got this error. Column 'respo' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: updated my answer.  You also should not use select *, but rather uniquely identify the columns you want reeturned.  However, I don't know what columns you want.

Comment: As I update it. It shows no record. Ill send you a dummy system and database. If its ok with you?

Comment: no record means either there are no matches between dv.dv_id and pr.dv_id OR none that match your where clause.

Comment: your right. What happen is that in tbl_dv there is a record while in tbl_payroll dont have. But its a big problem now. The record will only show if it has a match record dv_id on both 2 tables. Now when there is no record match it wont display anything. :( All i wanted was to add the ROLLS column to show the total rolls. Not vanishing records that dont have the match..

Comment: @user3571148 that's how an inner join works.  Are you wanting all records on tbl_payroll whether they have a match on tbl_dv, all records on tbl_dv whether they have a match on tbl_payroll, or all records on both tables regarldess of matches

Comment: i was expecting even it can find match records in both tables it will still display records.. :( sad

Comment: Try the modified query

Comment: I got an error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_payroll pr on dv.dv_id = pr.dv_id WHERE dv.respo='PEO' ' at line 3

Comment: My mistake, full outer joins don't exist in MySQL  Updating query now.

Comment: I have his error Not unique table/alias: 'pr'. How to display the ROLLS? I use $row[rolls]; still it wont display.. See my Answer where I post below that is the view.php code i was working for it..

Comment: I tweak your code to this: $viewrecord = "SELECT *, (pr.roll1 + pr.roll2 + 
                pr.roll3 + pr.roll4 + pr.roll5 + pr.roll6) as rolls 
 FROM tbl_dv dv LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_payroll pr on dv.dv_id = pr.dv_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_payroll tpr on dv.dv_id = tpr.dv_id 
 WHERE dv.respo='".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."' 
 && year(dv.date_added)='$year' && month(dv.date_added)='$month'";  BUT now how can i display the ROLLS I declared. $row[rolls]; wont display from database. I want it even if its not in tbl_payroll it will display a 0.00 value.